Flutter: Listen to audio live streamed over rtmp
I am making a audio live streaming application, i have already made the server and the app but i cant figure out how to listen to the audio stream. My stream is in the rtmp format and in video format, but i only want to listen to the audio. I have tried different packages but none of them worked
For example the stream_rtmp package gives me this error:
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method startStream on channel stream_rtmp)
and i cant find any solutions for that. (it has nothing to do with video because the error comes up even when the streaming server is offline)

I have found an solution to do this.
Using the flutter_vlc_player package you can create a video player and give it the size of 0 using a SizedBox
final VlcPlayerController controller = VlcPlayerController.network(
    'rtmp://url/live', 
    autoPlay: false
);

 @override
 void dispose() async {
     super.dispose();
     await controller.stopRendererScanning();
     await controller.dispose();
 }

SizedBox(
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    child: VlcPlayer(
        controller: controller,
        aspectRatio: 16/9,
        placeholder: 
            Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()
    )),
 )

and then you can control the playback using controller.play() or controller.pause()
